# Spark Session as another user

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

From Spark2.X we can create multiple sessions , can we create a session with different user than default in secure cluster.

```
spark1 = Session(default user)
spark2 = Session(different user)switch / impersonate / passing kerberos key tab file
```

Comment: I don't see any such API for creating Spark session.

Comment: That's what the Spark Thrift Server does : run a different session for each connected user, by impersonating that user, using the Hadoop authentication lib built on top of JAAS. Good luck with that.